# Flutter Desktop - focus input fields in the form

Tags: forms, flutter, desktop-application, flutter-layout

I am developing an application for the desktop with Flutter. I had to implement the form with multiple input fields. I really need to make the whole focus flow and I have used the `FocusNode` class to move from one input field to another. Everything is based on the submit event, so when I hit the `Enter` button on the keyboard it moves to the next field. It is pretty ok, but I have to change it from `Enter` key to `Tab` key which is more natural for the desktop users. Have you got any idea what can I do here to achieve such a result? Is there a way to trigger the `submit` event by different key (than Enter)?

Answer (score 1):

[This bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31946) is for making it easy to bind keys to actions. Once that's complete, one of the intended use cases is to [add tab support for form field navigation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/1608). There's been a lot of work in that area recently, so I wouldn't recommend putting time into working around this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I hope this will be done shortly because I find it very useful in my project